# Multiple Local storage locations check

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, local-storage, qr-code

I am creating an app and I have hit a problem when checking if several local storage locations exist. What I need to do is hide the links if there they have no href, and show them if they have a href. It needs to check this on page load.

I currently have this code which worked so far however because the app doesn't refresh page load won't function. Any ideas?

```
scanner.scan( function (result) { 

        if (result.text == "1.html" ) { //Checks barcode scanner result
            var onepageL = "1.html"; // links to file
            localStorage.setItem("onepage", onepageL); //saves link to local storage
        window.open(onepageL); //opens page
        }

$('a').each(function showhide() {
    (!$(this).attr('href')) ? $(this).hide() : $(this).show();
    });
```

I had the code above but this just disables all links with no href, and even when the scanner populates them they dont appear. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what showing/hiding links has to do with local storage.
Here is some code that will show all links that have an href and hide all others on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href]').show();
  $('a').not('[href]').hide();
});
```

Comment: The links are populated dynamically, and therefore have to be stored in local storage otherwise the links will be lost on app close. This method doesn't work for me.